# Entity framework adding existing classes to Entity Framework Model Diagram

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hi I'm new to Entity Framework so excuse me if this question seem simple, but I have tried to find an example or question where this is described.

I have built a webApi interface with classes in what I call an eventmodell. The Interface and model is working well to receive stuff. But now I would like to build the CRUD functions to the database with Entity Framework.

I have added an empty code first model, but then I don't now how to generate csdl, msl and ssl files needed to create the database.

I have added Empty EF designer model but have found no way of adding an existing class to the designer.

I have installed EF Power Tools but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a misunderstanding on how Code First works as compared to Database First.

There is no designer needed in a Code First approach.  You add classes to your model, setup a `DbContext` and use Migrations to setup, and then at later stages, alter the database structure.

Checkout this tutorial: [Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)